# Apply colgroup class only to some rows

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables, colgroup

I am trying to separate a group of columns with a border and I am having troubles to keep the headers and footers without that border.

Here's a fiddle with the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cgVHz/1/

As you can see, the two headers of the table also has a border, which is not what I'm looking for.

I am trying to overwrite the `colgroup` border but I don't get it working:

```
.demo{
    border-collapse: collapse; !important
}
.demo th{
    text-align:center;
    border-right:0px;
}
.demo colgroup{
    border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
}
```

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `.demo colgroup` to `.demo td` and it works as expected.

Comment: It doesn't do the same. Colgroup defines a group of columns for which i want to apply the stlyes. `td` will be applied to every `td`...